# Как ускорить выборку?

Tags: c#, lambda

есть 2 класса. 1:М

```
    public class master
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<detail> det { get; set; }
        public master ()
        {
            det=new List<detail>();
        }
    }
    public class detail
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int id_master { get; set; }
        public virtual master mast { get; set; }
    }
```

оба содержат по 10тыщ записей

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            mm.Add(new master() { id = i });
            dd.Add(new detail() { id = i, id_master = i });
        }
```

в мастер добавляю делали:

```
mm.ForEach(f => f.det.AddRange(dd.Where(w => w.id_master == f.id)));
```

выполняется пару сек. При 20тысячах возрастает до 10сек. Есть ли какие варианты про ускорение? Думаю всё дело в подзапросе .Where()

Comment: Вообще по сути `LINQ` медленее  `foreach` и уж `for` подавно. `for` также обойдет и `foreach`, `for` не создает мусор, как делает это `LINQ` и `foreach`. По этому для огромных манипуляций, рекомендую для обходов и выборок использовать `for` с обычным итератором и счетчиком..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы делаете линейный поиск в списке из 20000 элементов 20000 раз. Время поиска квадратично зависит от `n`, как Вы уже заметили. Если нет возможности воспользоваться предложением от @Vlad, распределите объекты `detail` по спискам в соответствии с их `master_id`, а потом добавьте содержимое этих списков в объекты `master`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
  mm.Add(new master() { id = i });
  dd.Add(new detail() { id = i, id_master = i });
}

Dictionary<int, List<detail>> byMasterId = new Dictionary<int, List<detail>>();
foreach(detail d in dd)
{
  List<detail> details;
  if (byMasterId.ContainsKey(d.id_master))
  {
    details = byMasterId[d.id_master];
  } 
  else
  {
    details = new List<detail>();
    byMasterId[d.id_master] = details;
  }
  details.Add(d);
}

foreach(master m in mm)
{
  if (byMasterId.ContainsKey[m.id])
    m.det.AddRange(byMasterId[m.id]);
}
```